# Executing Alexa Tutorial Code ALWAYS Fails - Beginner

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm new to Alexa Skill development and I'm sure this issue is process/environmental due to lack of experience.

Whenever I try to use a sample from an offical Alexa tutorial, I can never get the skill to pass the first TEST - always getting an error :(

In this case I am trying to run and fiddle with this tutorial:
https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/TxHGKH09BL2VA1/New-Alexa-Skills-Kit-Template-Step-by-Step-Guide-to-Build-a-Decision-Tree-Skill

**What is happening / What I've done:**

- I download the Node SDK from the Git link, I also download the sample from the Git link. I then create a new ZIP that contains the sample code with the Node SDK included in the path /src/alexa-sdk/
- I go to AWS and create a new function, not using a blueprint. I 'author from scratch' and create a function with the Skills Kit as a trigger. I name the function and use Node 6.10 runtime.
- I upload my ZIP file and leave all boxes default, for Role I choose Custom Role then pick Basic Execution from the Role screen.
- I leave the rest blank, go to NEXT and CREATE.

The function is created okay, but I do see this error 'This function contains external libraries. Uploading a new file will override these libraries.'

**Here's the problem** - this is the point of failure on all tutorials I've tried so far. I go to Configure Test Event, I choose ALEXA START SESSION as the template and click Save And Test...

EXECUTION RESULT FAILED:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/index'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)"
  ]
}
```

Here's something from associated error logs, unsure if it's useful:

```
Unable to import module 'index': Error
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

**I have noticed two things that I suspect may be an issue:**

1) When I go to the CODE tab for this function, I see this message:

```
Your Lambda function "testprojectx" cannot be edited inline since the file name specified in the handler does not match a file name in your deployment package.
```

2) When I look at the code that's inserted into the test when I choose ALEXA SESSION START, I see many instances of 'unique value here':

```
amzn1.echo-api.session.[unique-value-here]
```

Although, there is no mention of this in the tutorial link I am referencing.

I'm really downhearted about it now as this is like the 3rd tutorial code I've tried to configure. Can anybody with experience follow the steps I've taken and point me in the right direction.

Thank you SO MUCH in advance if so.

**EDIT: Absolute Clarification on how I am creating the ZIP file**
I'm using Windows 10 and Chrome to download the files from GitHub.

- I download the skill-sample-nodejs-decision-tree-master ZIP file from GitHub,
- I do not know how to use NPM so I do this simply via downloading to desktop.
- I then download the alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs-master.ZIP file to desktop.
- I unzip the contents of decision-tree-master into a folder on the desktop also called alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs-master.
- Within this folder, I navigate to /src/ and create a new folder called 'node_modules' within /src/.
- Within /src/node_modules/ I now create another new folder called 'alexa-sdk'.
- I unzip the contents of alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs-master.zip into /src/node_modules/alexa-sdk/.

I have tried two approaches from here - both fail:

1) I ZIP only the contents of /src/ (not including the /src/ folder itself) and upload to Amazon.

2) I ZIP the entire 'decision-tree-master' folder and upload to Amazon.

I must be missing something, as I said this is just one of many Alexa tutorials I've tried to get working and this always happens :( So disheartened now.

Comment: Does my answer help to sort out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue I have seen in many posts. Most of the cases it is the way zipping the files making the problem. Instead of zipping the folder you have to select all files and zip it like below,

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I have not yet been able to confirm or deny it works, I will mark your answer as accepted answer as soon as I can.

Comment: I'm afraid this did not work. The scenario is the same. I will update the question with some new information to absolutely clarify the process I am using. Thanks for your time, perhaps you can still help

Comment: Do you mind the send me .zip file to me? I don't need you business logic or anything but just the skeleton you are using. Please share it to codewithvijay@gmail.com.

Comment: Thank you @Vijayanath Viswanathan, that is most kind. There is no business logic yet as I am just trying to set up the tutorial as a test for experimentation. Have sent .zip.

Comment: @PhilGill sorry I didn't get you .zip yet to my gmail, codewithvijay@gmail.com.

Comment: Should be with you now @Vijayanath Viswanathan - I had to try sending from gmail too as hotmail is experiencing problems. I have tried to upload the zip to amazon again, just to clarify, the CODE tab within AWS Lambda is showing the code from the tutorial, but the TEST is still failing. Could this issue be due to the Role configuration? I created custom role and basic execution. If you can't run the code from my ZIP, can you run the code from the tutorial download?

Comment: Basic execution role will be enough to run code in Lambda. You need advanced role only if you are trying to connect with other services from Lambda (like DynamoDB and all). If you can't share it in email please upload in cloud somewhere and share the url

Comment: I have sent a link to the ZIP file from my gmail account. Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: I have replied to your mail. Please try a let me know :)